# Python - How to sort individual elements in a list of Python tuples

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I apologize of if this is a duplicate of this.

[Sort a list of tuples depending on two elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376384/sort-a-list-of-tuples-)
depending-on-two-elements

What I have is a unsorted list of tuples

```
unsorted_list  = [(50,45), (35,40)]
sorted_list = [(35,40), (50,45)]
```

I want to end up with the following sorted list. I tried the following:

```
sorted(unsorted, key=lambda element: (element[0], element[1]))
```

My result was the following, which is not what I wanted.

```
[(35, 40), (45,50)]
```

Comment: Your output appears to be what you said you wanted, so it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: BTW, that particular key function is redundant: that's how two-element tuples will be sorted without a key function arg.

Comment: Sorry, I modified it to what I wanted. I want the numbers ordered throughout. Thanks!

Comment: I think you've got those outputs mixed up. You say that "I want the numbers ordered throughout", but in the question you say that your result was `[(35, 40), (45,50)]`, "which is not what I wanted".

Comment: Bear in mind that tuples are immutable, so you can't simply sort their contents. You have to create new tuples that contain the sorted items of the old tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable, so you can't simply sort their contents. You have to create new tuples that contain the sorted items of the old tuples. Here's a simple way to do that with a list of two-item tuples.

```
unsorted_list = [(50,45), (35,40)]
sorted_list = [(min(t), max(t)) for t in sorted(unsorted_list)]
print(sorted_list)
```

**output**

```
[(35, 40), (45, 50)]
```

Another option is

```
sorted_list = [(u, v) if u<=v else (v, u) for u,v in sorted(unsorted_list)]
```