# Stable sorting in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

It is possible to apply the [sort filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#sort) in Jinja2 successively to sort a list first by one attribute, then by another? This seems like a natural thing to do, but in my testing, the preceeding sort is completely unstable and all sorting is lost.

I already worked around it by sorting first in python before passing the list to the template, but I would like to know if it's possible to sort "stable" in Jinja2.

The way I applied the filter was like so:

```
{{ item_list|sort(attribute='value')|sort(attribute='color') }}
```

What I had hoped to see was the list sorted by `color`, with the elements sharing a color sorted by `value`. Instead, it looked the same as if the `value` sort never happened.

For example, from this list:

```
2 red
3 blue
3 red
2 blue
1 blue
4 red
```

I would like something like this:

```
1 blue
2 blue
3 blue
2 red
3 red
4 red
```

I looked at the [groupby](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#groupby) filter but that implementation seems too complicated (would require nested for loops).

Comment: Jinja2 will pass your list to first sort function and sort by `value`. The returned list is then passed to second sort function and again sorted by `color`. Obviously it is as good as sorting a list only by `color`, so the first sort gets `overwritten`

Comment: @RedBaron What you're missing, I believe, is that in this example, you can have elements that share a color but have different values. I'll add an example output to clarify.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not aware of a native jinja2 filter that can do this. To sort a list based on multiple attributes,you can define a [custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters) in jinja2.

From the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes), you can write your own filter

```
import operator

def sort_multi(L,*operators): 
    L.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(*operators))
    return L
```

Register it in your application environment. So for `pyramid`, you would do something like

```
env = config.get_jinja2_environment()
env.filters['sort_multi'] = sort_multi
```

And finally in your templates

```
{{item_list|sort_multi('value','color')}}
```

Comment: This looks like an elegant solution. I'll try it out (in Flask) and accept if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Just over the top of my head. Does passing a tuple to `attribute` in `sort()` work?

Comment: Still haven't had a chance to test this, but looking at the [sort How To](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html), I assume no. Also, I should be using operator.attrgetter instead of itemgetter.