# How to sort multiple attributes in Jinja when one doesn't exist?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I'm sorting a dictionary like this:

```
{% for s in selected.values() | sort(attribute="last_name") | sort(attribute="first_name") | sort(attribute="middle_initial") %}
```

But sometimes the input dictionary doesn't contain `last_name`, how could I go about sorting the dictionary in the event the key isn't present? I'd like to use a default value similar to how you would access a dictionary in Python3 as such:

```
selected.get('last_name', 'Unknown')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stable sorting in Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143053/stable-sorting-in-jinja2)

Comment: Just to highlight what's discussed in Kostas' dupe link: Jinja2's `sort` filter **does not** support chaining to sort by multiple levels. So your code, even if it didn't fail on missing `last_name`s, would only effectively sort on `middle_initial` (the last one).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can check that a variables exist with

```
{% if my_variable %}
   do something
{% end if%}
```

So perhaps you can check if an attribute exists with

```
{% if object_list.attribute %}
   do something
{% end if%}
```