# Dynamic sorting of list on varying number of attributes

Tags: python, sorting

i've seen solutions to sorting lists based on a fixed number:
[Sort a list by multiple attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes)

It has a nice sorted solution:
s = sorted(s, key = lambda x: (x[1], x[2]))

and also the itemgetter example

However I have a varying number of attributes, an example can be with 2 attributes:

```
example_list = [{'d1_desc': 'a', 'd1_sort': 1, 'd2_desc': 'x': 'd2_sort': 30},
    {'d1_desc': 'b', 'd1_sort': 2, 'd2_desc': 'x': 'd2_sort': 30},
    {'d1_desc': 'a', 'd1_sort': 1, 'd2_desc': 'y': 'd2_sort': 35},
    {'d1_desc': 'c', 'd1_sort': 3, 'd2_desc': 'z': 'd2_sort': 38},
    etc.
]
```

But it can also be 1 or 3 or more. I cannot use this the lambda function like this or the itemgetter. However I do know the number of dimensions at time of execution (even though it varies from case to case).
So i've made this (with parameter set for the 2 dim example):

```
example_list = [{'d1_desc': 'a', 'd1_sort': 1, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
    {'d1_desc': 'b', 'd1_sort': 2, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
    {'d1_desc': 'a', 'd1_sort': 1, 'd2_desc': 'y', 'd2_sort': 35},
    {'d1_desc': 'c', 'd1_sort': 3, 'd2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38},
    {'d1_desc': 'a', 'd1_sort': 1, 'd2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38},
    {'d1_desc': 'b', 'd1_sort': 2, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
    {'d1_desc': 'c', 'd1_sort': 3, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
    {'d1_desc': 'b', 'd1_sort': 2, 'd2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38}
]

def order_get( a , nr):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, nr+1):
        result.append(a.get('d' + str(i) + '_sort'))
    return result

example_list.sort(key = lambda x: order_get(x, 2)) # for this example hard set to 2

In [82]: example_list
Out[82]: 
[{'d1_desc': 'a', 'd1_sort': 1, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
 {'d1_desc': 'a', 'd1_sort': 1, 'd2_desc': 'y', 'd2_sort': 35},
 {'d1_desc': 'a', 'd1_sort': 1, 'd2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38},
 {'d1_desc': 'b', 'd1_sort': 2, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
 {'d1_desc': 'b', 'd1_sort': 2, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
 {'d1_desc': 'b', 'd1_sort': 2, 'd2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38},
 {'d1_desc': 'c', 'd1_sort': 3, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
 {'d1_desc': 'c', 'd1_sort': 3, 'd2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38}]
```

But is this really the best way to do this? And with that i mean 1) Pythonic and 2) performance wise? Is this a common issue or not?

Comment: This is an okay thing to do, but it makes me wonder if you really need a list of dicts rather than a list of lists/tuples. Because, you know, your keys have order. But since we only see a part of the picture, I can't tell for sure. Edit: there's also `OrderedDict`, you can consider it as well.

Comment: True, i can control the order (and make it a list); actually hadn't thought about it, will try the performance impact this week. thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

I would still use an `itemgetter` since it's faster and you create it once and use every time:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def make_getter(nr):
    keys = ('d%d_sort' % (n + 1) for n in xrange(nr))
    return itemgetter(*keys)

example_list.sort(key=make_getter(2))
```

To create the `itemgetter` requires time. If you have to use it on more than one list, since it is always the same, store it `get_two = make_getter(2)` and use `get_two` as `key` function.

Comment: Will try it and post a performance comparison later this week!

Answer (score 1):

You can support an arbitrary number of sort keys so long as they have a predictable pattern as keys.

Suppose you have `d[X]_sort` to `d[Y]_sort` where X and Y are integers and the sort keys all end in `_sort` with a key function like so:

```
import re

def arb_kf(d): 
    li=filter(lambda s: s.endswith('_sort'), d) 
    rtr=[tuple(map(int, re.findall(r'([0-9]+)', k) + [d[k]])) for k in li]
    rtr.sort()            
    return rtr
```

With your example list of dicts:

```
example_list = [{'d1_desc': 'a', 'd1_sort': 1, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
    {'d1_desc': 'b', 'd1_sort': 2, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
    {'d1_desc': 'a', 'd1_sort': 1, 'd2_desc': 'y', 'd2_sort': 35},
    {'d1_desc': 'c', 'd1_sort': 3, 'd2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38},
    {'d1_desc': 'a', 'd1_sort': 1, 'd2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38},
    {'d1_desc': 'b', 'd1_sort': 2, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
    {'d1_desc': 'c', 'd1_sort': 3, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
    {'d1_desc': 'b', 'd1_sort': 2, 'd2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38}
]


>>> for d in sorted(example_list, key=arb_kf) :
...     print d  
{'d2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30, 'd1_sort': 1, 'd1_desc': 'a'}
{'d2_desc': 'y', 'd2_sort': 35, 'd1_sort': 1, 'd1_desc': 'a'}
{'d2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38, 'd1_sort': 1, 'd1_desc': 'a'}
{'d2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30, 'd1_sort': 2, 'd1_desc': 'b'}
{'d2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30, 'd1_sort': 2, 'd1_desc': 'b'}
{'d2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38, 'd1_sort': 2, 'd1_desc': 'b'}
{'d2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30, 'd1_sort': 3, 'd1_desc': 'c'}
{'d2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38, 'd1_sort': 3, 'd1_desc': 'c'}
```

Suppose that the integer in `d[X]_sort` is different in some of the dicts and you want to give more weight to lower numbers; i.e., `d0_sort` carries more sort weight than a dict that does not have the lower number.

Since Python sorts tuples element, this holds true:

```
>>> sorted([(1,99), (1,1,1), (0,50), (1,0,99)])
[(0, 50), (1, 0, 99), (1, 1, 1), (1, 99)]
```

Since the key function is returning a list of tuples, that also works in this case.

Then if your example list has a dict with `'d0_sort': 3` in it, that will sort higher than anything with `'d1_sort` in it:

```
example_list = [{'d1_desc': 'a', 'd1_sort': 1, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
    {'d1_desc': 'b', 'd1_sort': 2, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
    {'d1_desc': 'a', 'd1_sort': 1, 'd2_desc': 'y', 'd2_sort': 35},
    {'d1_desc': 'c', 'd1_sort': 3, 'd2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38},
    {'d1_desc': 'a', 'd1_sort': 1, 'd2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38},
    {'d1_desc': 'b', 'd1_sort': 2, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
    {'d1_desc': 'c', 'd1_sort': 3, 'd2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30},
    {'d1_desc': 'b', 'd1_sort': 2, 'd2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38},
    {'d1_desc': 'b', 'd0_sort': 3, 'd2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38}
]
>>> for d in sorted(example_list, key=arb_kf) :
...     print d  
{'d0_sort': 3, 'd2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38, 'd1_desc': 'b'}
{'d2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30, 'd1_sort': 1, 'd1_desc': 'a'}
{'d2_desc': 'y', 'd2_sort': 35, 'd1_sort': 1, 'd1_desc': 'a'}
{'d2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38, 'd1_sort': 1, 'd1_desc': 'a'}
{'d2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30, 'd1_sort': 2, 'd1_desc': 'b'}
{'d2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30, 'd1_sort': 2, 'd1_desc': 'b'}
{'d2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38, 'd1_sort': 2, 'd1_desc': 'b'}
{'d2_desc': 'x', 'd2_sort': 30, 'd1_sort': 3, 'd1_desc': 'c'}
{'d2_desc': 'z', 'd2_sort': 38, 'd1_sort': 3, 'd1_desc': 'c'}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try it later this week; always have some difficulties with regex, should spend more time on it I guess. This is a good incentive :)