# Sorting 2 columns at once

Tags: python, excel, sorting, csv, delimiter

Im trying to sort these data in :
- in alphabetical order with each person's highest score for the tests
- by the highest score

Answer (score 1):

Already asked an answered. See [Sort a list by multiple attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes)

Also Both list.sort() and sorted() accept a reverse parameter with a boolean value.

One answer from the link

```
import operator
s = sorted(file, key = operator.itemgetter(1, 2),reverse=True)
```

Comment: if you think a question is a dupe you should mark it as one not use an answer from the dupe

Comment: How do I mark an answer as a duplicate?

Comment: You hit close and select duplicate of ..

Comment: just below the questin tags

Comment: I do not have enough points to do this.

Comment: If you paste the link into the comments it will be linked, there is 10 more points!

Comment: @RobertJacobs Hello , I also tried that but it wouldnt sort the average and also the name at the same time.