# how to sort cells in a column in CSV and the cells corrsponding to that using Python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, sorting

I have a list named

```
l=[('Altamont','TN'),('Baxter','TN'),('Norway','SC'),('Trenton','SC')]
```

initially,  which is in the order of `('cities', 'states')`

After sorting based on states and cities, and writing to `CSV` by below the functions,

```
def calcDistance(self):
 filePath = self.dlg.fileNameEdit.text()
 l=[('Altamont','TN'),('Baxter','TN'),('Norway','SC'),('Trenton','SC')]
 sorted(l, key=operator.itemgetter(1,0))
self.writeToFile(l, filePath)

def writeToFile(self, l, filePath):
    fileCSV = open(filePath, "w")

    for i in l:
          fileCSV.write(i)
          fileCSV.write(",")
          fileCSV.write("\n")
          QMessageBox.information(self.dlg, "Number of Cities Near", str(len(lsOfCities)) + " citie(s) are written to "+filePath)
          fileCSV.close()
          self.dlg.close()
```

After it runs, I will be getting a `CSV` file as below:

```
'Baxter','TN'
'Altamont','TN'
'Trenton','SC'
'Norway','SC'
```

I want to know that **whether there is any possible way in `Python2.7`, if I do sorting on the second column (i.e states) of the `CSV`, the cells corresponding to that should also be sorted?**

like

```
'Norway','SC'
'Trenton','SC'
'Altamont','TN'
'Baxter','TN'
```

Comment: what is lsOfCities of `for i in lsOfCities:` ?

Comment: sorry that is by mistake and now i had edited that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort by `state name`, then by `city name`, the flowing code :

```
sorted(l, key=operator.itemgetter(1,0))
```

doesn't make any sense, because here `l` is still immutable. You should re-assign:

```
l = sorted(l, key=operator.itemgetter(1,0))
```

After this sorting ,I tried in my computer:

```
>>> l = [('Altamont','TN'),('Baxter','TN'),('Norway','SC'),('Trenton','SC')]
>>> import operator
>>> l = sorted(l, key = operator.itemgetter(1,0))
>>> l
[('Norway', 'SC'), ('Trenton', 'SC'), ('Altamont', 'TN'), ('Baxter', 'TN')]
```

Comment: Well your code is fine if i want to sort by city name, then by state name. But i need to sort by state first and then by city.And please make note that my list in the form of (cities, state). Please can you edit your answer for it?I am new to python.

Comment: `(1, 0)` means sorted by second item, then first item, so I have done sorted by 'state' first, and please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes

Comment: Yeah i agree its state first and cities second. my final output awrites as shown below                                                                                Ballentine SC
Bamberg SC
Barnwell SC
Batesburg SC
Bath SC
Baxter TN
Baker Hill AL
Bangor AL
Banks AL

Comment: But i need is to appear like this                                                                                              Baker Hill AL
Bangor AL
Banks AL                                                                              Ballentine SC
Bamberg SC
Barnwell SC
Batesburg SC
Bath SC                                                                                            Baxter TN. I want the first alphabet of the state column along with its corresponding cell to be my first cell and so on.

Comment: @harinish: When I copy the exact list of cities and states from your comment, `random.shuffle` it, then use the exact code from this answer, I get the exact result you want. Just as you should expect. You're clearly not doing the same thing the answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are sorting the list and not assigning it to anything.

```
def calcDistance(self):
  filePath = self.dlg.fileNameEdit.text()
  l = [('Altamont','TN'),('Baxter','TN'),('Norway','SC'),('Trenton','SC')]
  l = sorted(l, key=operator.itemgetter(1,0))
```

See example below:

```
>>> a = [4,3,2]
>>> sorted(a)
[2, 3, 4]
>>> a
[4, 3, 2]
>>>
```