# Python customized sort

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I have a list of dictionary objects (read from csv) that I want to sort. E.g.

```
l_data.sort(key=lamdba x: (x['fname'], x['lname']))
```

Now I want to make the code more flexible, and want to sort on the keys based on the input, something like:

```
def sort_data(l_data, keys):
    l_data.sort(key=lambda x: (x[d] for d in keys))
    ... ...
```

And I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: generator() < generator()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(x[d] for d in keys)` is a generator expression (produces `generator` object). If you want to make a tuple, wrap that generator expression with `tuple(...)`:

```
def sort_data(l_data, keys):
    l_data.sort(key=lambda x: tuple(x[d] for d in keys))
    # code
```

Though your code can be greatly simplified using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

def sort_data(l_data, keys):
    l_data.sort(key=itemgetter(*keys))
    # code
```

Comment: Thanks! itemgetter is really pythonic!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sort by the generator `x[d] for d in keys`, the output of the generator needs to be converted to a tuple first.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes)