# Counter: ordering elements with equal counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections

The docs specify that for [`collections.Counter.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter),

> elements with equal counts are ordered arbitrarily.

I'm interested in a concise way to order first by frequency/value descending (the default), but then secondarily by key, ascending.  (Key is just the 0th element of each tuple from `.most_common()`.)

Example:

```
from collections import Counter
arr1 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5]
arr2 = [3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5]  # Same values, different order

print(Counter(arr1).most_common())
print(Counter(arr2).most_common())
# [(1, 3), (3, 3), (2, 2), (5, 1)]
# [(3, 3), (1, 3), (2, 2), (5, 1)]
```

Desired result (for both `arr2` and `arr2`):

```
[(1, 3), (3, 3), (2, 2), (5, 1)]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just sort it appropriately:

```
sorted(Counter(arr2).most_common(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```