# How to sort a file alphabetically by named column, python, csv

Tags: python, csv, sorting, python-2.x

I have three csv files each with three named columns, 'Genus', 'Species', and 'Source'. I merged the files into a new document and now I need to alphabetize the columns, first by genus and then by species. I figured I could do this by first alphabetizing the species, and then the genus and then they should be in the proper order, but I haven't been able to find anything online that addresses how to sort named columns of strings. I tried lots of different ways of sorting, but it either didn't change anything or replaced all the string in the first column with the last string.

Here's my code for merging the files:

```
import csv, sys

with open('Footit_aphid_list_mod.csv', 'r') as inny:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inny)

    with open('Favret_aphid_list_mod.csv', 'r') as inny:
        reader1 = csv.DictReader(inny)

        with open ('output_al_vonDohlen.csv', 'r') as inny:
            reader2 = csv.DictReader(inny)

            with open('aphid_list_complete.csv', 'w') as outty:
                fieldnames = ['Genus', 'Species', 'Source']
                writer = csv.DictWriter(outty, fieldnames = fieldnames)
                writer.writeheader() 

                for record in reader:
                    writer.writerow(record)
                for record in reader1:
                    writer.writerow(record)
                for record in reader2:
                    writer.writerow(record)

                for record in reader:
                    g = record['Genus']
                    g = sorted(g)
                    writer.writerow(record)

inny.closed
outty.closed
```

Comment: first store all the data in a list of rows _then_ sort, _then_ write back to file.

Comment: you may find this page useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you files aren't insanely large, then read all the rows into a single list, sort it, then write it back:

```
#!python2
import csv

rows = []

with open('Footit_aphid_list_mod.csv','rb') as inny:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inny)
    rows.extend(reader)

with open('Favret_aphid_list_mod.csv','rb') as inny:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inny)
    rows.extend(reader)

with open('output_al_vonDohlen.csv','rb') as inny:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inny)
    rows.extend(reader)

rows.sort(key=lambda d: (d['Genus'],d['Species']))

with open('aphid_list_complete.csv','wb') as outty:
    fieldnames = ['Genus','Species','Source']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outty,fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: This worked! The only thing is that because I'm using 2.7, I had to remove all the 'newline=' attributes from 'open'- but everything was just fine without them.

Comment: @birdoptera Updated. Note use of binary mode instead of `newline=''` for Python 2 per csv documentation.