# Sort a nested list in python having dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list in the below given format:

```
{'DetectedText': 'RAZZAQ', 'Type': 'WORD', 'Id': 11, 'ParentId': 1, 'Confidence': 98.4175796508789, 'Geometry': {'BoundingBox': {'Width': 0.13082271814346313, 'Height': 0.07997149974107742, 'Left': 0.05101994425058365, 'Top': 0.03755004703998566}, 'Polygon': [{'X': 0.050936006009578705, 'Y': 0.03812778368592262}, {'X': 0.1816418319940567, 'Y': 0.038123928010463715}, {'X': 0.18164214491844177, 'Y': 0.11644938588142395}, {'X': 0.05093633010983467, 'Y': 0.11645323783159256}]}}
{'DetectedText': '123456', 'Type': 'WORD', 'Id': 10, 'ParentId': 0, 'Confidence': 99.44573974609375, 'Geometry': {'BoundingBox': {'Width': 0.1333530694246292, 'Height': 0.0828823447227478, 'Left': 0.7199195027351379, 'Top': 0.028442291542887688}, 'Polygon': [{'X': 0.7201741337776184, 'Y': 0.028222769498825073}, {'X': 0.8533148169517517, 'Y': 0.03051863983273506}, {'X': 0.8531182408332825, 'Y': 0.11106494814157486}, {'X': 0.7199775576591492, 'Y': 0.10876907408237457}]}}
{'DetectedText': 'ABDUL', 'Type': 'WORD', 'Id': 12, 'ParentId': 2, 'Confidence': 98.67652893066406, 'Geometry': {'BoundingBox': {'Width': 0.11256816983222961, 'Height': 0.074801966547966, 'Left': 0.04738632217049599, 'Top': 0.14951731264591217}, 'Polygon': [{'X': 0.04746600240468979, 'Y': 0.1498059332370758}, {'X': 0.1596333384513855, 'Y': 0.15002737939357758}, {'X': 0.15961268544197083, 'Y': 0.2239050269126892}, {'X': 0.04744535684585571, 'Y': 0.22368358075618744}]}}
{'DetectedText': 'BED:', 'Type': 'WORD', 'Id': 13, 'ParentId': 2, 'Confidence': 98.10992431640625, 'Geometry': {'BoundingBox': {'Width': 0.08710028976202011, 'Height': 0.07596106827259064, 'Left': 0.6397669911384583, 'Top': 0.14786238968372345}, 'Polygon': [{'X': 0.6399385929107666, 'Y': 0.14720818400382996}, {'X': 0.7270201444625854, 'Y': 0.14760403335094452}, {'X': 0.7269713878631592, 'Y': 0.22334450483322144}, {'X': 0.6398898363113403, 'Y': 0.22294865548610687}]}}
{'DetectedText': 'G3/26', 'Type': 'WORD', 'Id': 14, 'ParentId': 2, 'Confidence': 99.2603759765625, 'Geometry': {'BoundingBox': {'Width': 0.11345399171113968, 'Height': 0.08469167351722717, 'Left': 0.7426034212112427, 'Top': 0.14282099902629852}, 'Polygon': [{'X': 0.7428475022315979, 'Y': 0.14198169112205505}, {'X': 0.8559787273406982, 'Y': 0.14304040372371674}, {'X': 0.8558661937713623, 'Y': 0.2279675006866455}, {'X': 0.7427350282669067, 'Y': 0.22690877318382263}]}}
```

I want to sort the list based on:

```
(text['Geometry']['Polygon'][0]['Y']) and if both are same , then for 
(text['Geometry']['Polygon'][0]['X'])
```

The script I tried is :

```
textL.sort(key = lambda x: x['Geometry']['Polygon']['0']['Y'])
```

assuming the list is stored in textL , but it is giving me error.

> File "detect-text.py", line 20, in 
>       textD.sort(key = lambda x: x['Geometry']['Polygon']['0']['Y'])     TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the error provide any sort of hint about what may be causing it?

Comment: I added the error, but I have no idea how to sort it then. :(

Comment: You have `'0'` in quotes. You should have `0` (no quotes). That's what the error is saying.

Comment: It is telling you quite clearly that list-indices must be integers, but you are passing a string...

Comment: What if 'Y' is same for 2 elements ?

Comment: You can pass a tuple as the key. Try this: `textL.sort(key = lambda x: (x['Geometry']['Polygon'][0]['Y'], x['Geometry']['Polygon'][0]['X']))`. More here: [sort list by multiple attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the integer `0`, you are passing `"0"`, which will crash for a list, as the `__getitem__` is expecting an integer for an index:

```
textL.sort(key = lambda x: (x['Geometry']['Polygon'][0]['Y'], x['Geometry']['Polygon'][0]['X']))
```