# Sorting list with two conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of strings I would like to sort. However, some strings are one word, others are two words. Also, I would like to first sort by the second word, then the first.

I'm relatively new to the idea of lambda functions and also how a key works for the sort() method, so I've tried the following (which doesn't work):

```py
list_to_sort = ['1 month', '1 year', '3 months', '3 years', '6 months', 'daily']

def sort_func(x):
    x.split()
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x[0]
    else:
        return x[1]

cols.sort(key=sort_func)

# I would like the output to be: 
# ['daily', '1 month', '3 months', '6 months', '1 year', '3 years']
```

Instead, the list doesn't change at all. I'm not too certain how the "key=" works in the sort() method though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a list by multiple attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes)

Comment: What are you sorting by (length, alphabetical order, etc)?

Comment: Your required output requires more logic than your current code (even if worked "as expected") has. How would it know that `'years'` has more significance than `'months'`?

Comment: @DeepSpace Alphabetically, daily>month>months>year>years. So sorting by the last word would get be the order I want, no?

Comment: @JrAnalyst If you want pure alphabetical order then yes. If you want a more logical one then no. For example, if you have `['2 years', '999 days']` then after sorting you will have `['999 days', '2 years']` (which is correct alphabetically but wrong mathematically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution:

```
list_to_sort = ['1 month', '1 year', '3 months', '3 years', '6 months', 'daily']

list_to_sort = sorted(list_to_sort, key=lambda x: tuple(reversed(x.split())))
print(list_to_sort)

# >> ['daily', '1 month', '3 months', '6 months', '1 year', '3 years']
```

**NB**: This should work wathever the number of words is, including empty strings.

Example:

```
['', 'daily', '2 months 1 day', '3 months', '6 months', '1 year', '3 years']
```

**Update**: Keep in mind that the numbers in your strings will be sorted by as characters, not as integers:

```
['1', '11', '2', ...]
```

If you want to avoid this, the line above should be changed to:

```
list_to_sort = sorted(list_to_sort, key=lambda x: tuple(reversed([float(item) if item.isnumeric() else item for item in x.split()])))
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It will sort by number lexicographically. Add "11 months'" your list and see what happens.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I will try and understand it now.

Comment: @cs95 you're obviously right, but OP asked about sorting strings, what this solution does. But I'll add an update on that matter.

Comment: @cs95 Just saw the issue! For my limited needs, the solution still works, but you're correct that in general it would not.

Comment: Updated to take care of the integers

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there, `x.split()` returns a new list, so you would need to assign the return value to a variable. Also since one of your word after splitting is a float, you need to take care of it when creating the key

```
list_to_sort = ['', '1 month', '1 year', '3 months', '3 years', '6 months', 'daily', '11 months', '12 years']

def sort_func(x):

    #Assign result of split to li
    li = x.split()

    #If 1 element, return word, 0
    if len(li) == 1:
        return li[-1], 0
    #If 2 elements, return word and number cast to int
    elif len(li) == 2:
        return li[-1], int(li[0])

    #If no elements, return empty string and 0
    else:
        return '',0

list_to_sort.sort(key=sort_func)
print(list_to_sort)
```

The output will be

```
['', 'daily', '1 month', '3 months', '6 months', '11 months', '1 year', '3 years', '12 years']
```

Answer (score 1):

`.split` is not in place. `x.split()` creates a list and throws it away.

Since you are essentially sorting by the last word (if you have 1 word then the "last word" is that 1 word), a better implementation  for `sort_func` would be

`return x.split()[-1]`

or as a lambda:

```
cols.sort(key=lambda x: x.split()[-1])
```