# Sorting arrays in NumPy ascending on one column and descending on other column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, matrix

How can I sort 2d array in NumPy by the 1st column ascending and 2nd column descending?

For example,

```
a = array([[9, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 0, 5],
           [7, 1, 6]])
```

Result :

```
array([[4, 5, 6],
       [7, 1, 6],
       [7, 0, 5],
       [9, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `np.lexsort` function for this

```
import numpy as np
a = np.asarray([[9, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6],
           [7, 0, 5],
           [7, 1, 6]])

a[np.lexsort((-a[:, 1], a[:, 0]))]
```

Output

```
array([[4, 5, 6],
       [7, 1, 6],
       [7, 0, 5],
       [9, 2, 3]])
```