# How to sort files in python that have more than 1 number?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

So I've got some files that look like this .../100keV8cm.txt.  This goes from 1-10 cm and 80,100,120 keV.  The problem is that when I try to sort them, it places 1-9cm in the correct order for all energies but it places the 10cm one for each energy at the end of the appended list.  This is the code I have so far:

```
for i in range(emin,emax+steps,steps):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if f'{i}keV' in filename:
            input_files.append(directory + filename)
        else:
            continue
    emin+=steps
    input_files.sort(key=lambda f: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, f))))
```

I want it to go 1-10cm for 80keV, then the next 10 files for 100keV and so on.

Comment: Sorry, correction.  The last line should not be indented.  It should be out of the for loops.

Comment: You can [edit] the question to fix that. Also note @Nikaido has suggested an edit to fix the formatting, which I suggest you approve first.

Comment: Just write the `lambda` to return tuple of the values instead of single value. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233482/9327628