# Python Sort Multidimensional List first element Based on second element that already sorted

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional List like this (the second element already sorted)

```
    [[92, 25], [93, 25], [95, 27], [94, 27], [94, 27], [92, 27], [89, 27], [89, 27], [92, 27], [91, 30], [90, 30], [90, 30], [90, 30], [91, 30]]
```

So i want to sort the first element base on the second element (Descending). Expected Output:

```
    [[93, 25], [92, 25], [95, 27], [94, 27], [94, 27], [92, 27], [92, 27], [89, 27], [89, 27], [91, 30], [91, 30], [90, 30], [90, 30], [90, 30]]
```

Comment: Right, so what went wrong with what you found about sorting by multiple items in sublists?

Comment: Can you explain *why* this is the expected output?  And what have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: Also note that you're calling this an "array" but it isn't in Python, it's a list. 99% of the the time, "array" refers to NumPy array. There is also a Python array but it's barely ever used.

Comment: Aw i think i just solved my own problem by search at stackoverflow with your keyword mates @roganjosh 
i found itemgetter and it solved my own question like with 3 repeat lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me get this straight, you want a list to be sorted first based on the *second* element in a tuple in *ascending* order, and break any ties by the *first* element in *descending* order?

You can do that with `sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[0]))`, assuming your elements are numbers. If not you have to write a more complex comparison function.

Comment: Cool, so your answer is just the same as my suggested dupe, which you could have hammered with

Comment: @roganjosh That "dupe" does not involve different orderings (ascending/descending) for different columns of the data.

Comment: Mmm, yes it does. But ok.

Comment: @roganjosh Where does it say that?

Comment: In the comments under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233482/4799172) which lead to another dupe target

Comment: @roganjosh So I was supposed to approve your suggestion of a duplicate because that question contained an answer which had a comment which linked to a relevant question? Ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do in place sort than

`arr.sort(key=lambda x:(x[1], -x[0])`

otherwise can use sorted

`sortedArray = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[0]))`

Comment: Oops saw @roganjosh 's duplicate and definitely its a duplicate item