# Python min() use two keys

Tags: python, min

How can I use two keys in Python builtin `min`/`max` functions?

For example, I have a `list` of `dict`s (they serve as counters) like this:

```
[{88: 3, 68: 0, 6: 0}, {88: 2, 68: 1, 6: 0}, {88: 3, 68: 0, 6: 1}, 
 {88: 2, 68: 1, 6: 1}, {88: 3, 68: 0, 6: 2}, {88: 2, 68: 1, 6: 2}, 
 {88: 2, 68: 0, 6: 3}, {88: 2, 68: 1, 6: 0}, {88: 1, 68: 2, 6: 0}, 
 {88: 2, 68: 1, 6: 1}]
```

and I want to know which counter has the minimum cost:

```
cost = lambda d: sum(k * v for k, v in d.items())
```

as well as the minimum count:

```
count = lambda d: sum(d.values())
```

I know how to do it in normal code. I just wonder if there is any pythonic way to do this.

Comment: By "as well as" do you mean `and` or min of sum or least of either?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I mean and. It should have the minimal cost and the minimal count.

Comment: @MarkMeyer But you are doing int and int which would mostly return 1. I am thinking maybe like `lambda d: (cost(d), count(d))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the exact same method you would use for [`sort`ing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes):

```
>>> my_list = [{88: 3, 68: 0, 6: 0}, {88: 2, 68: 1, 6: 0}, {88: 3, 68: 0, 6: 1},
               {88: 2, 68: 1, 6: 1}, {88: 3, 68: 0, 6: 2}, {88: 2, 68: 1, 6: 2},
               {88: 2, 68: 0, 6: 3}, {88: 2, 68: 1, 6: 0}, {88: 1, 68: 2, 6: 0},
               {88: 2, 68: 1, 6: 1}]

>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda d: (sum(k * v for k, v in d.items()), sum(d.values())))
[{88: 2, 68: 0, 6: 3}, {88: 1, 68: 2, 6: 0}, {88: 2, 68: 1, 6: 0}, {88: 2, 68: 1, 6: 0}, 
 {88: 2, 68: 1, 6: 1}, {88: 2, 68: 1, 6: 1}, {88: 2, 68: 1, 6: 2}, {88: 3, 68: 0, 6: 0},
 {88: 3, 68: 0, 6: 1}, {88: 3, 68: 0, 6: 2}]

>>> min(my_list, key=lambda d: (sum(k * v for k, v in d.items()), sum(d.values())))
{88: 2, 68: 0, 6: 3}

>>> max(my_list, key=lambda d: (sum(k * v for k, v in d.items()), sum(d.values())))
{88: 3, 68: 0, 6: 2}
```