# How to sort eigenvalues in python/numpy first by real part then by imaginary part

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, spyder, complex-numbers

I have calculated the eigenvalues of a 5x5 jacobian matrix while looping over a parameter R.

I get both real and complex eigenvalues as expected, but all are given in complex form. The issue I am having is that `numpy.sort` sorts these values by the real part of each eigenvalue which is useful to a point, but the real part of each eigenvalue is either increasing/decreasing as I vary R.

Thus there becomes a point where I need to sort by imaginary part also to keep each eigenvalue in the same entry in the output array. The picture below shows what I mean. I get 3 real eigenvalues displayed in positions 2, 3 and 4 in the array jumping to positions 0,1 and 4. How can I sort by imaginary part? I have added my code below.
[Eigenvalues switching column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW1jc.png)

```
import numpy.linalg as la

for a,b,c,d,e,f in zip(T_S, T_C, S_S, S_C, w, R):

    eigvals = la.eigvals(np.array([[-f, e, 0, 0, b], 
                                   [-e, -f, 0, 0, -a], 
                                   [0, 0, -f, e, d],
                                   [0, 0, -e, -d, -c], 
                                   [-1/(2*F), 0, D/(2*F), 0, -1/F]]))

    eigvals = np.sort(eigvals)
    print(np.round(eigvals, decimals = 3))
```

EDIT: Upon thinking about this, I don't think sorting is going to help me here. Thanks to those who answered.

I wish to keep the purely real eigenvalue in the same position in the array for each iteration. The sorting is precisely what is making it change position.

```
  for i = 4.2 eigvals = [-0.33-4.16j -0.33+4.16j -0.33+0.j    0.  -4.2j   0. +4.2j ]
  for i = 4.3 eigvals = [-0.35+0.j   -0.33-4.26j -0.33+4.26j  0.  -4.3j   0.  +4.3j ]
```

In the i = 4.2 case the real root is in position 2 but for i = 4.3 the real part decreases so np.sort moves it to position 0.

I am not sure there is an easy way around this but any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list by multiple attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the input and the desired output. Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where you explain input / output / desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but I'll try to answer at least this key element:

> How can I sort by imaginary part ?

You can simply exchange temporarily the real and imag parts:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-1+1j, 0-1j, 1])

def xch_real_imag(arr):
    return a.imag + 1j * a.real

print(a)
imag_sorted = xch_real_imag(np.sort(xch_real_imag(a)))
print(imag_sorted)
```

yields

```
[-1.+1.j  0.-1.j  1.+0.j]
[ 1.-1.j -1.+0.j  0.+1.j]
```

If you need a more precise answer about your case, please edit your question with a reproducible example, that will help the community try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to sort an `np.array()` of complex numbers first by `real` part and then `imaginary` part. At least, I think that's the main thing on your question.

Say you have:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([3+4j, 1+2j, 3+3j, 3+2j])
```

Numpy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) on `numpy.sort()` states:

> The sort order for complex numbers is lexicographic. If both the real
>   and imaginary parts are non-nan then **the order is determined by the
>   real parts except when they are equal, in which case the order is
>   determined by the imaginary parts**.

So, there you go, `numpy` takes care of that for you, no need to fancy operations. For the example above, you can do:

```
print(a)
x = np.sort(a)
print(x)
```

**Outputs:**

```
[3.+4.j 1.+2.j 3.+3.j 3.+2.j] # prior to sorting

[1.+2.j 3.+2.j 3.+3.j 3.+4.j] # sorted
```

Note how the 3 last items have the same real part (3), and three different imaginary partas (2, 3, 4) and how they are sorted in increasing order.