# Comparing Class Objects in python with specified conditions

Tags: python, list, sorting, oop, iterable

I have a list of Objects of class Student

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,id,name,cgpa):
        self.id=id
        self.name=name
        self.cgpa=cgpa
    def __str__(self):
        return "Id:{} Name:{} CGPA:{}".format(self.id,self.name,self.cgpa)

student_objects = [ Student(33,'Rumpa',3.68), Student(85,'Ashis',3.85), Student(56,'Samiha' 3.75), Student(19,'Samara',3.75), Student(22,'Fahim',3.76),]
```

Now I have to sort these student objects first with cgpa in **DESCENDING** order. If both have the same cgpa then order them using the name in **ASCENDING** order and if both have the same name, order them by using their ID which is unique for every student.

Generally for sorting i use sorted(Iterable,key='',reverse=''). But how can I add the **CONDITION** where I can go to the next step where if both have the same cgpa I can sort them by using their name.

Comment: You can e. g. use a key function which returns a tuple of kind (-cgpa, name).

Comment: sorted_students = sorted(student_objects, key = lambda x: (-x.cgpa, x.name))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list by multiple attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
>>> list(map(str, sorted(student_objects, key=lambda e: (-e.cgpa, e.name))))
['Id:85 Name:Ashis CGPA:3.85', 'Id:22 Name:Fahim CGPA:3.76', 'Id:19 Name:Samara CGPA:3.75', 'Id:56 Name:Samiha CGPA:3.75', 'Id:33 Name:Rumpa CGPA:3.68']
```

Parsing that out:

```
sorted(student_objects, key=lambda e: (-e.cgpa, e.name))
    # key function        ^    ^
    # Create a tuple                   ^               ^ 
    # Negative cgpa for descending.    ^
    # then name                                     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You may implement `__lt__` function in your class.

```
def __lt__(self, other):
    if self.cgpa==other.cgpa:
        return self.name<other.name

    return self.cgpa<other.cgpa
```

Comment: There may be many ways to sort students; only one can take advantage of a predefined `__lt__` operator, and the others will still have to make use of the `key` argument to `sorted`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `key=lambda x: (-x.cgpa, x.name)`, but this trick only works because there is an easy way to map `int` values to values that reverse the order of the sort.

A cleaner solution is to define a comparison function, then use `functools.cmp_to_key` to create an appropriate key function for use with `sorted`.

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

def ordering(s1, s2):
    if s1.cgpa > s2.cgpa:
        return -1  # s1 comes first
    elif s1.cgpa < s2.cgpa:
        return 1  # s2 comes first
    else:  # They're equal, fall back to name
        if s1.name < s2.name:
             return -1
        elif s1.name > s2.name:
             return 1
        else:
             return 0

student_objects = [ Student(33,'Rumpa',3.68), Student(85,'Ashis',3.85), Student(56,'Samiha' 3.75), Student(19,'Samara',3.75), Student(22,'Fahim',3.76),]

sorted_students = sorted(student_objects, key=cmp_to_key(ordering))
```

---

`ordering` can be defined more succintly:

```
# Python 2 had this built in.
def cmp(x, y):
    return -1 if x < y else 1 if x > y else 0


# Note the order of the arguments in the two calls to cmp
def ordering(s1, s2):
    return cmp(s2.cgpa, s1.cgpa) or cmp(s1.name, s2.name)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is how you want to do it

```
class Student:
        def __init__(self,id,name,cgpa):
            self.id=id
            self.name=name
            self.cgpa=cgpa
        def __str__(self):
            return "Id:{} Name:{} CGPA:{}".format(self.id,self.name,self.cgpa)

student_objects = [ Student(33,'Rumpa',3.68), Student(85,'Ashis',3.85), Student(56,'Samiha', 3.75), Student(19,'Samara',3.75), Student(22,'Fahim',3.76),]

student_objects.sort(key=lambda x: x.cgpa, reverse=False)

for s in student_objects:
    print(s.cgpa)
```