# Sorting based on frequency and alphabetical order

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to sort based on frequency and display it in alphabetical order
After freq counting , I have a list with `(string, count)` tuple
E.g `tmp = [("xyz", 1), ("foo", 2 ) , ("bar", 2)]`

I then sort as `sorted(tmp, reverse=True)`
This gives me `[("foo", 2 ) , ("bar", 2), ("xyz", 1)]`

How can I make them sort alphabetically in lowest order when frequency same, Trying to figure out the comparator function

expected output:`[("bar", 2), ("foo", 2 ), ("xyz", 1)]`

Comment: Hi Dusan, from the link you provided sorted(counter.items(),key = lambda i: i[0]) will just sort based on alphabetic order. I need to freq sort them, then if frequency is same alphabetically. 
temp  = [("xyz", 1), ("foo", 2 ) , ("bar", 2) , ("abc",1)]
print sorted(temp,key = lambda i: i[0]) return [('abc', 1), ('bar', 2), ('foo', 2), ('xyz', 1)]

Comment: Say hi to your classmate: [Python sort by two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65095608/python-sort-by-two-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sort by multiple keys.

```
sorted(tmp, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```

Source: [Sort a list by multiple attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes).

Comment: Hi, I need to sort one key in descending, other in ascending. Seems need to write a custom sort.

Comment: Updated, notice the `-` sign in `-x[1]`.

Comment: Happy to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
from operator import itemgetter

tmp = [('xyz',1), ('foo', 2 ) , ('bar', 2)]
print(sorted(tmp, key=itemgetter(0,1)))
```

This skips the usage of function call.