# How do we sort a list of objects based on multiple parameters in python

Tags: python

So my class is

```
class Student:
        
    raise_amt = 1.8
    no_of_students = 0
    def __init__(self, id, name, age, salary):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.salary = salary
        
        
        Student.no_of_students+=1
        
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Student({}, {}, {}, {})".format(self.id, self.name, self.age, self.salary)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "Student user: {}, name:{}, age:{}".format(self.id, self.name, self.age)
```

And I have created an object with 3 objects

```
s1 = Student(10, "Pranav", 21, 1200)
s2 = Student(20, "Pranav", 22, 1500)
s3 = Student(30, "tejas", 22, 5999)

students = []

students.append(s1)
students.append(s2)
students.append(s3)
```

The sort function given is

```
students.sort(key = lambda x:x.name)
```

**I WANT TO SORT THE LIST IN SUCH A WAY THAT IF NAMES ARE EQUAL, IT SHOULD THEN CHECK AGE AND IF THAT IS EQUAL ASWELL THEN SALARY**

Basically the equivalent of the comparator class in Java

Comment: Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want just return sorting key as a tuple of necessary fields:

```
students.sort(key = lambda x: (x.name, x.age, x.salary))
```

Try full working code [here online](https://tio.run/##jVLRaoQwEHz3KxafDA1ilIOecP9Q6GMpkjaxTatRklg8Sr/dbtSrhh60QpJ1dnZ2J6Q/u9dOF9P03HBr4d4NQmpXRrB@c2C4srLirYMTsPR2xnRXdXVlF77FRDbDQtZQVUorV1WJlU1NQQkKmreSAn/BzfKGmzPZWnhWqgRKKBGCvgphf4QJFEIc9xBepDGzBKGJIFh9pqGLmxMLqTtLRvZmtbSb3Ug3GA3xqpd8flHYFonTujMtd8nqkW6@6I8Tuh@eRNeaW/d3bxisNOXc2euXPkB1PP81BYEosgzv7mKFZRTiO8M1/4gp5IwCy7OMRDbfkfKQlCPpMJOKHanwJCffuF05h@PxSLDd9ngeHrfflPe91CKxjPzG8itYsdNKbWdc8i79K2h4@yQ4jCUk4@p2XC58vNw2VvZG4YyXejJN3w) .

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to implement magic methods like `__gt__` (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__gt__) in your class and let the standard operators do what they are supposed to do. The standard `sort` function will work like a charm letting the objects know how to compare themselves.