# How to sort elements of list in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, compare

there are 4 dictionaris in a list:

```
mylist = [{'name': 'c', 'age': 21}, {'name': 'b', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'd', 'age': 21}, {'name': 'a', 'age': 20}]
```

if I want to sort this by age, then I should use:

```
mylist.sort(key= lambda psn: psn['age'])
```

then output would be:

```
mylist = [{'name': 'b', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'a', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'c', 'age': 21}, {'name': 'd', 'age': 21}]
```

now! what if i want to sort this list by 'age' but if there were any same ages, then i sort just those persons by name ?
in this list, 'a' and 'b' have same ages. and also 'c' and 'd' have same ages too. so how can i sort this list by 'age' but if there were any same ages sort them by 'name' ? (alphabetically)

should be this:

```
mylist = [{'name': 'a', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'b', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'c', 'age': 21}, {'name': 'd', 'age': 21}]
```

Comment: Do not use list as variable as it's shadowing the `list` type.

Comment: @ MetallimaX Its hurt to the eyes to see it T.T !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list by multiple attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `key` argument of `sorted` function. To sort first by `age` and then by `name` you can return a `tuple`, something like this:

```py
>>> list = [{'name': 'c', 'age': 21}, {'name': 'b', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'd', 'age': 21}, {'name': 'a', 'age': 20}]
>>> sorted(list, key=lambda x:  (x['age'],x['name']))
[{'age': 20, 'name': 'a'}, {'age': 20, 'name': 'b'}, {'age': 21, 'name': 'c'}, {'age': 21, 'name': 'd'}]
>>>
```

BTW, use a different name for your variable `list` 'cause it would hide built-in `list`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer you're right. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to also consider the name secondly, just return tuple (I use the word `arr` Instead of your `list`):

```
 sorted(arr, key=lambda x: (x['age'],x['name']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a composite key, e.g. using `operator.itemgetter` to make it more readable:

```
from operator import itemgetter

lst.sort(key=itemgetter("age", "name"))
```

Python's sorting algorithm [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) also works well when sorting data in multiple rounds taking advantage of partial sorts (this would be more relevant if you wanted to sort by the second key in descending order for instance and a composite key is not so easily obtainable). It is even a [recommended pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts) in the sorting docs:

```
lst.sort(key=itemgetter("name"))
lst.sort(key=itemgetter("age"))  # stable wrt first run
```

Notice that you do the rounds in reverse order of priority.