# Sort sublists twice based on two elements in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, sublist

I'm trying to sort sublists based on the second element and then sort again based on the third element, both in descending order. So, something like this

```
[('b',7,9),('c',8,3),('a',7,10)]
```

becomes this

```
[('c',8,3),('a',7,10),('b',7,9),]
```

I think I need to something like print(sorted(list1, key=lambda l:...., but I'm not sure how to complete the code.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233482/10987432)

Comment: s = sorted(s, key = lambda x: (x[1], x[2]), `reverse=True`)     <<Try this.