# Sort list of list python

Tags: python, list

I have an output like this:

```
[['ca'], 0.62]
[['ca', 'tf'], 0.62]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se'], 0.71]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz'], 0.71]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd'], 0.42]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd', 'fbs'], 0.12]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd', 'fbs', 'th'], 0.56]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd', 'fbs', 'th', 'ex'], 0.56]
```

The numbers in the right represent a score, I would like to sort them so I could have it that way:

```
[['ca', 'tf', 'se'], 0.71]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz'], 0.71]
[['ca'], 0.62]
[['ca', 'tf'], 0.62]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd', 'fbs', 'th'], 0.56]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd', 'fbs', 'th', 'ex'], 0.56]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd'], 0.42]
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd', 'fbs'], 0.12]
```

Higher score with less features first.
I used this command:

```
li.sort(reverse=True)
```

but I got this error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'
```

Any idea how to do this properly ?

=====

## Edit from Joe Ferndz

@DNZ, please consider this as your input:

```
li = [[['ca'], 0.62],
[['ca', 'tf'], 0.62],
[['ca', 'tf', 'se'], 0.71],
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz'], 0.71],
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd'], 0.42],
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd', 'fbs'], 0.12],
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd', 'fbs', 'th'], 0.56],
[['ca', 'tf', 'se', 'zz', 'rd', 'fbs', 'th', 'ex'], 0.56]]
```

And the solution for this has already been posted by @Ali Shanoon. That should solve for it.

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like you're trying to sort the list `[['ca'], 0.62]`. Are you sure you're sorting the list of scores, not just the first highscore?

Comment: Adding to that, it looks like the code in your first block is equivalent to `li = [['ca'], 0.62]`.

Comment: Are you sure `li` is defined correctly? Are you missing commas at the end of `[['ca'], 0.62]`

Comment: @SilvioMayolo What I want basically is just the first high score, I was trying to sort the lists reversely so I could select just the first high score.

Comment: @JoeFerndz, That's the point, the output is like this, no commas after the list.

Comment: @DNZ `li = [['ca'], 0.62]`. Your list-literal is incorrect.

Comment: @DNZ, i am not talking about the output. I am talking about the input. I think it is missing a comma and also missing a `[]` at the outside.

Comment: I think you need to update the sample input. @DNZ

Comment: Here's a more general answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes

Answer (score 2):

You were close. Sorted can take a key.

```py
sorted(li, reverse=True, key=lambda x: (x[-1], -len(x[0])))
```