# How do I sort a list of tuples by both elements?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of tuples, for example `[(1800, 3), (4000, 5), (1999, 4), (2000, 1), (2001, 2)]`. I need a list of a set length (3, for example) using any combination of these tuples where BOTH elements are sorted in ascending order, like `[(2000, 1), (2001, 2), (4000, 5)]`. So `[(1800, 3), (1999, 4), (2000, 1)]` wouldn't work because it's sorted by the first element but not the second. Is it possible to sort a list the way I need?

Comment: that's impossible, like how conceptually can you sort something by two things at once

Comment: @Hippolippo yeah that's fair, thanks

Comment: @Sable Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes/4233482) out my friend

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "So `[(1800, 3), (1999, 4), (2000, 1)]` wouldn't work because it's sorted by the first element but not the second" Well, *what do you want the code to do* if that is the input?

Comment: Looking more closely, it seems like you want to *choose a subset* of the input that has the desired property. Consider: what will you do if there is more than one valid subset? What will you do if there are no valid subsets? Also, please title your question in a way that reflects the *actual question*.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a sorting problem; it is a kind of search problem, since you're searching for a subset of the elements which satisfies some criteria.

You can solve it as follows. Sort the list normally, i.e. by first component (using the second component as a tie-breaker); then you are looking for an increasing subsequence in the second component. You can find a [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) using a standard algorithm. If this subsequence is not long enough, then there is no solution (so return `None` or raise an error); if it is longer than necessary, then simply slice it to the right size.