# Sort elements in list based on length first and alphabetical order second

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list with strings. Now, I want to sort the elements in this list based on string length.

```
proxy_list = ['my', 'list', 'looks', 'like', 'this']
```

My desired output looks as follows:

```
desired_output = ['my','like','list','this','looks']
```

The code below sorts the list based on length, but not on alphabetical order:

```
print(sorted(proxy_list, key=len))
>>> ['my', 'list', 'like', 'this', 'looks']
```

How can I sort a list with string based on two things?

Comment: `key=lambda s: (len(s), s)`. Sort on length first, on strings second. Strings are sorted alphabetically be default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list by multiple attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes)

Comment: Since python `sort` is stable, you could also run `sorted(sorted(proxy_list), key=len)`, although this will probably be slower unless the list is already more or less sorted as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `key` argument of sorted function. convert each element to a tuple of priority. here (len(s), s), this means `len(s)` have more priority to `s`.

```python
proxy_list = ['my', 'list', 'looks', 'like', 'this']
print(sorted(proxy_list, key=lambda s: (len(s), s)))
#>>> ['my', 'like', 'list', 'this', 'looks']
```