# Sort underscore before upercase letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a `DataFrame` with `UPPERCASE` column names from a database that I'd like to sort. Some of them are prefixed with an underscore `_`. The default sorting puts them at the end. Do I have to convert them to lowercase, then sort, then convert them back to uppercase or is there an easier way?

Here's some sample data. When the values of `cl2` are lowercase then the order is *correct*. With uppercase not so much.

```py
pd.DataFrame({
   "cl1": ["foo", "foo", "foo"], 
   "cl2": ["_FOO", "BAR", "BAZ"]}
).sort_values(["cl1", "cl2"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If conversion to lowercase works for you, you can use it as a key:

```
pd.DataFrame({
   "cl1": ["foo", "foo", "foo"], 
   "cl2": ["_FOO", "BAR", "BAZ"]}
).sort_values(["cl1", "cl2"], key=lambda s: s.str.lower())
```

Other option, sort by the strings without `_`, then the presence of `_`:

```
(pd.DataFrame({
   "cl1": ["foo", "foo", "foo"], 
   "cl2": ["_FOO", "BAR", "BAZ"]})
   .sort_values(["cl1", "cl2"], key=lambda s: s.str.lstrip('_'))
   .sort_values(["cl1", "cl2"], key=lambda s: ~s.str.startswith('_'), kind='stable')
)
```

output:

```
   cl1   cl2
0  foo  _FOO
1  foo   BAR
2  foo   BAZ
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar peculiar results.

For me, I had a list of tuples I was trying to sort on a compound key.

I ended up using replace to remove underscores in the sort itself as follows:

```
  dl = sorted(dl, key=lambda t: (t[0].replace('_',''),t[1]))
```

Otherwise I was getting odd results like:

- SAPHIRE

coming before:

- SAP_AG

It's bizarre how Python sort works.

I tried both of the results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3121985/495157) in conjunction with [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233482/495157) to come up with this.