# How to Implement Multi-Level Sorting of a List of Dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sorting

I am working with a list of dictionaries in Python that represents a set of data records. The data structure looks like this:

```
data = [
    {'Name': 'Tom', 'Age': 25, 'Score': 85},
    {'Name': 'Alex', 'Age': 30, 'Score': 80},
    {'Name': 'Tom', 'Age': 20, 'Score': 90},
    {'Name': 'Alex', 'Age': 25, 'Score': 95},
    {'Name': 'Tom', 'Age': 25, 'Score': 80},
    {'Name': 'Alex', 'Age': 30, 'Score': 85}
]
```

Each dictionary in the list represents a single record with 'Name', 'Age', and 'Score' as fields. My goal is to sort this list of dictionaries according to multiple fields. I want to sort it first by the 'Name' field in alphabetical order, then by the 'Age' field in ascending numerical order, and finally by the 'Score' field in descending numerical order.

I have been trying to use the sorted() function in Python, but I can't figure out how to sort by multiple fields at once, and especially not how to sort by different fields in different directions.

I would like to know the most efficient way to achieve this multi-level sort in Python. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this an exercise or a real-life problem? For the later you may want to check [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Thank you for your suggestion. It's actually a real-life problem, and while I agree pandas would be great for handling this kind of data manipulation, I am currently working in an environment where pandas cannot be used. Therefore, I am looking for a solution with native Python data structures. But I'll definitely consider pandas for future projects where it can be utilized

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list by multiple attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `key=` parameter in `sorted()` or `.sort()`. The key parameter will return 3-item tuple, where the score is negated (to have it in descending order):

```py
data.sort(key=lambda d: (d["Name"], d["Age"], -d["Score"]))
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {"Name": "Alex", "Age": 25, "Score": 95},
    {"Name": "Alex", "Age": 30, "Score": 85},
    {"Name": "Alex", "Age": 30, "Score": 80},
    {"Name": "Tom", "Age": 20, "Score": 90},
    {"Name": "Tom", "Age": 25, "Score": 85},
    {"Name": "Tom", "Age": 25, "Score": 80},
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear and concise answer. I've seen -d["Score"] used in a lambda function for sorting. Why does negating d["Score"] cause it to be sorted in reverse order?

Comment: @BimeshPerera Because `.sort()` in default mode sorts in ascending order. So the lower numbers are positioned first. (In this example -95 is lower number than -85)

Comment: Ah, I see! That makes sense, considering the default behavior of the sort() function. Thank you for the clear explanation