Sort a list of lists when one of the sort items is text month
I am trying to sort this list of lists by the year and then by month,I can get the years part sorted but am stuck when I try to do secondary sort by month. I have created a dict and a list to try to use to sort.
my code:
from operator import itemgetter

import pandas as pd

month_list = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
months = {
    'Jan': 0,
    'Feb': 1,
    'Mar': 2,
    'Apr': 3,
    'May': 4,
    'Jun': 5,
    'Jul': 6,
    'Aug': 7,
    'Sep': 8,
    'Oct': 9,
    'Nov': 10,
    'Dec': 11,
}
data = [['Sep', '2024', 112], ['Dec', '2022', 79], ['Apr', '2023', 114], ['Aug', '2024', 194], ['May', '2022', 140], ['Jan', '2023', 222]]

half_sorted = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(1))
input(half_sorted)

My Output so far:
[['Dec', '2022', 79], ['May', '2022', 140], ['Apr', '2023', 114], ['Jan', '2023', 222], ['Sep', '2024', 112], ['Aug', '2024', 194]]


https://stackoverflow.com/a/4233482/1368703
Although, depends on the exercise. Datetime objects will sort correctly, so that's what I would choose if it wasn't an assignment.

import pandas as pd

month_list = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
months = { 'Jan': 0, 'Feb': 1, 'Mar': 2, 'Apr': 3, 'May': 4, 'Jun': 5, 'Jul': 6, 'Aug': 7, 'Sep': 8, 'Oct': 9, 'Nov': 10, 'Dec': 11, }
data = [['Sep', '2024', 112], ['Dec', '2022', 79], ['Apr', '2023', 114], ['Aug', '2024', 194], ['May', '2022', 140], ['Jan', '2023', 222]]

sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: (int(x[1]), months[x[0]]))


print(sorted_data)

The code sorts the data list first by year (ascending) and then by the month's order using the months dictionary.

Thank you so much. I have been banging my head on the wall for a while now.

Why is it importing pandas?

I was trying to put the data in a dataframe and use pandas to sort.

You can conveniently create your month lookup dictionary with locale specific data from the calendar module.
You don't seem to take account of the 3rd value in the sub-lists. As those values are all different (in your sample) it doesn't really matter. However, it probably makes sense to account for that value for situations where your list has multiple entries for a certain year / month pair.
Therefore, I suggest:
import calendar

months = {m: i for i, m in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr[1:])}

data = [
    ["Sep", "2024", 112],
    ["Dec", "2022", 79],
    ["Apr", "2023", 114],
    ["Aug", "2024", 194],
    ["May", "2022", 140],
    ["Jan", "2023", 222],
]

def key(lst):
    month, year, n = lst
    return int(year), months.get(month, -1), n

print(*sorted(data, key=key), sep="\n")

Output:
['May', '2022', 140]
['Dec', '2022', 79]
['Jan', '2023', 222]
['Apr', '2023', 114]
['Aug', '2024', 194]
['Sep', '2024', 112]

